# Rails 3: Ruby url_encode method not found; undefined method `u' for #<SiteController:0x007fe447774da8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple line of code: `@keyword = u @keyword` and rails is throwing me an exception that it's not a method:

`undefined method 'u' for #<SiteController:0x007fe447774da8>`

I am upgrading this app from Rails 2 to Rails 3. Was the url_encode method replaced by something else? It's hard to find documentation for it. I'm using the method in my controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `URI::encode()`:

```
require 'open-uri'
@keyword = URI::encode(@keyword)
```

I think `URI.escape()` should also work <- deprecated in `Ruby 1.9.2` apparently.
You can use `CGI.escape` instead of the above, not sure of the difference, if any.

And [you can still use url_encode if you do the following](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB/Util.html#method-c-url_encode):

```
require "erb"
include ERB::Util

@keyword = u(@keyword)
```

Comment: worked great. I didn't need to require open-uri though. Thanks!!

Comment: Actually a quick Google shows that `escape` has been deprecated in `Ruby 1.9.2`